# Can anyone help identify why this wont execute properly? IF promblems with cast

Tags: c++, while-loop, include

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int run_t = 0;
char q_mos;
char i_pstring;

int main () {
    cout << "Would you like to write to the temporary datapcku database?\nSelect Y/N\n";
    cin >>  q_mos;
    if(q_mos = char(Y)){ //for some reason I am having time resolving the value of Y
        while(run_t=0){
            cout << "Running Input Operations.\n";
            cout << "Please provide me with a Question so it can be achrived in the Active DB(Directory)\n";
            cin >> i_pstring;
            cout << "Please tell me the answer...\n";
            cout << i_pstring;
        }
        run_t=1;
    } else {
        run_t=1;
        cout << "Booting into main operations...\n";
    }
    cout << "At diagnostic Boot menu, prepare for diagnostic on system config orginaztional routines.\n";
    ofstream binlib;
    binlib.open ("datapcku.bin", ios::app | ios::binary );
    binlib << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    binlib.close();
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

As is is apparent I wanted to use my run_t variable to control complete program maneuverability but I am having a time executing q_mos to cin input and I can not understand why the logic appears to be failing, as in the simple while loop following the q_mos comparison wont execute even one I get inside the block.
Do i need to convert q_mos to a string? And what could be affect my run_t variable while loop.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. Y is never declared before its use.

Comment: I'm guessing that `char(Y)` is intended to be `'y'` (or perhaps `'Y'`).

Comment: Eventually, I would like to convert the logical statements in this program to test through some form of binary manipulation. If possible. So I don't have to test for both.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things are wrong.

In your `if(q_mos = char(Y))` statement,

a) you are assigning, not comparing (use == instead of =). This also applies to your while loop.

b) replace `char(Y)` with `'Y'`, as you are passing it at the moment, Y is perceived to be a variable.

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck. I will make these changes this evening.